# I"m expected to change the given matrix to table to aggregate ytd py and ytd cy into a single table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I change a matrix into a table in PowerBi , for including ytd cy and ytd py calculations.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhIj.jpg)

I tried using switch(true, _____) what else can I do . please elaborate what else could be a possible method to change matrix into a table visualisation. how can I show ytd py and ytd cy in a single table in powerBI

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)